# Nuget package that puts a file into the project directory but not into the project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a very simple Nuget package for a C# solution that puts a file into the project directory but NOT into the actual project.

Setting `Target="Content"` inserts the file into the project. `Setting Target=""` gives an error:

> "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>    '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework."

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested I did solve this - it's necessary to produce a `.targets` file that copies the required file from the package to the required location. When the `.targets` file is included in the `.nuspec` file thus:

```
  <files>
    <file src="myfile.myfile" target="" />
    <file src="MyTargets.Targets" target="Build" />
  </files>
```

the error goes away, and MyFile.Myfile is copied by the build (and on package installation) as required.

If anyone wants more details, contact me.